# Get maximal value from lookup table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel worksheet with a table like this:

```
Index Threshold
1     0
2     10
3     20
...
```

Then I have another table with values:

```
Values
5
11
14
22
```

What I want is to implement a formula that maps the "Values" to the maximum "Index" that is possible without overshooting the "Threshold", for example:

```
Values    Threshold    Index
5      -> 0         -> 1
11     -> 10        -> 2
14     -> 10        -> 2
22     -> 20        -> 3
```

I think I can implement a binary tree of `IF()` with a cost of `log(n)`, but it is very cumbersome and unwieldy to handle. For example (`T*` are thresholds, `V*` are values and `I*` are indices):

```
IF(V1 < T3;IF(V1 < T2;I1;I2);IF(V1 < T4;I3;I4))
```

This is a balanced `IF()` tree like:

```
          T3
        /    \
     T2        T4
    /  \      /  \
  I1    I2  I3    I4
```

Is there a better (more usable) way to implement this?

This is just the gist of the actual sheet I'm working on. The real data is two-dimensional, spread on many pages and by far larger (hundreds of thresholds and thousands of values).

Especially copy&paste is very difficult to handle (create, test and maintain).

---

**EDIT:** actual solution

So, this is after some study of the matter and I want to show the solution that worked for me. The `MATCH()` function was fundamental, but not enough.

First of all, the thresholds don't indicate the *maximum allowed value* but the *minimum required value*. The title is therefore misleading. What I had to do is:

- reverse the threshold range;
- use `MATCH()` with the `-1` comparison type.

To reverse the range I used this formula, occupying cells in the `F2:F102` range:

```
INDEX(C$2:C$102;COUNTA(C:C)+1-ROW())
```

To match I used:

```
MATCH(D2;F$2:F$102;-1)
```

This last match is without `INDEX()` because the returned offset already is what I need.

Thanks to Scott Craner for putting me on the right tracks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E2,B:B,1))
```

You may need to use `;` instead of `,` for your local settings:

```
=INDEX(A:A;MATCH(E2;B:B;1))
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! I just tested it on a smaller dataset and generally it works, but there are indexing errors. All values are integers and the error appears only in higher values. For `T=5, V=4` it gives me the previous index `I=4`, not the correct `I=5`. Any idea how this can be? I cannot just add `+1` because for lower values (`V < 4`) it is correct. Adjusting it manually would skew the lower part into error :(

Comment: I had to leave, and will not be back for a few hours,  I am not understanding.  If I put `10` in E3 it gives me 2, should it be 1?

Comment: No, 2 is correct. What I'm working with is more complex data, but I can manage it by using an intermediate correction formula. The `MATCH()` is what I needed, so this question is accepted and done! Thank you very much and don't mind the previous comment :)

Comment: Hello. I added the actual solution to my question, which solves the *indexing error* I mentioned in the comment above.